# tikz: clip image with rounded corners and border

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, clip

I want to round corners of image and I want to have border around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,fadings}

\tikzset{ 
  photo/.style={ inner sep=1pt,clip,rounded corners=0.5cm }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[photo] at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=110mm]{chipping-sparrow-wiki-commons-1900x855.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[photo,draw=red!80,thick] at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=110mm]{chipping-sparrow-wiki-commons-1900x855.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The second tikzpicture gives me an error:
`! Package tikz Error: Extra options not allowed for clipping path command..`

And the result looks like this:[(Image by DickDaniels, CC-BY-SA, from https://www.innonmillcreek.com/blog/2017/01/north-carolina-mountain-birds-chipping-sparrow.html)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq7uo.jpg)

I guess I could use `\path` and `\node` combination, but I don't know image size.

How can I get clipped image with border in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clipped image is a node and can be named (`name=clipped`). Later a rectangle can be drawn like this:

```
\draw (clipped.south west) rectangle (clipped.north east);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,fadings}

\tikzset{ 
  photo/.style={inner sep=1pt,clip,rounded corners=0.5cm }
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[photo] at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=110mm]{chipping-sparrow-wiki-commons-1900x855.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[photo,name=clipped] at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=110mm]{chipping-sparrow-wiki-commons-1900x855.jpg}};
  \draw[red,thick, rounded corners=0.5cm] (clipped.south west) rectangle (clipped.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the image height with the command:

```
\pgfdeclareimage[width=110mm]{image1}{/path/your/image}
\settoheight{\imageheight}{\pgfuseimage{image1}}
```

After, I added a rectangle node with your desired options:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,fadings}

\tikzset{ 
  photo/.style={ inner sep=1pt,clip,rounded corners=0.5cm }
}
\newlength\imageheight

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=110mm]{image1}{bird.jpg}
\settoheight{\imageheight}{\pgfuseimage{image1}}


\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node[photo] at (0,0)
   {\includegraphics[width=110mm]{bird.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[photo] at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=110mm]{bird.jpg}};
    \node (rect) at (0,0) [draw,thick,minimum width=110mm,minimum height=\imageheight,draw=red!80,thick,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]